# Improbable doesn't mean impossible

Tags: measure-theory

Given a measurable space $(\Omega,\mathcal{F},\mu)$, what kind of conditions do we need to impose on $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mu$ to ensure that the only measurable set with measure zero is the empty set?

I believe the answer is that the singletons are in the measurable set and also have positive measure. However, if we take the $\sigma$-algebra generated by $(n,n+1]$, there are no measurable singletons; but I can define a measure (the trivial measure) that indeed satisfies the fact that there are non-empty measurable sets with measure zero.

Where is my error?